# Issues with installing Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, terminal, cocoapods

I'm trying to install cocoapods on my MacBook pro but every time I type in the command in terminal I receive this error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

I've been searching trying to find how to give myself writing permissions but haven't found anything that works yet.

Comment: Use a `brew install cocoapods` it should solve the issue